# Zend Database Mutli table "Select" via Join

Tags: php, zend-framework, postgresql

Using Zend DB. I am trying to figure out how to write this query using the DB Class.

```
select 
   org.orgid
   org.role
   user.userid
   user.firstname
from orgTable org
join userTable user on org.userid = user.userid
where org.orgid = 'generated-id'
```

from the documents I understand or think I understand how to do it with one definition using an AS like condition, but even then Im still not sure. Eventually this will branch out into a multi table join, based on cross table conditions so not sure how to achieve this to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what are you looking for

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );

$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('org' => 'orgTable'),
                    array( 
                        'orgid' => 'org.orgid', 
                        'role'  =>'org.role',
                        'userid'  =>'user.userid',
                        'firstname' =>'user.firstname'
                    ))
             ->join(array('user' => 'userTable'),
                    'org.userid = user.userid',array())
            ->where('org.orgid = ?',$generated_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Zend_Db_Select` that returns the result you are looking for.

```
    $select = $db->select()
                 ->from(array('org' => 'orgTable'), array('orgid', 'role'))
                 ->join(array('user' => 'userTable'), 'org.userid = user.userid', array('userid', 'firstname'))
                 ->where('org.orgid = ?', 'generated-id');
```

You can use the array notation for table names to get the aliased names in the query.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, that kinda makes more sense.. from the docs I was assuming I had to pass this sort of stuff around in the from bit some how to then get the aliases that way, but I couldnt find a reference for mutliple table based aliases, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **zend framework 2** , the following code helps you what are you looking for

```
$generated_id = 1 ;

$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select( array('org' =>'orgTable'));

$select->columns(array('orgid','role') )
       ->join( array('user' => 'userTable'),  
               'org.userid = user.userid', 
               array('userid','firstname')
       )->where( array('org.orgid' => $generated_id ) );
```

if your adapter platform is mysql, then for printing sql

```
$mysqlPlatform = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Mysql();
echo $select->getSqlString(  $mysqlPlatform );
```

which print sql as

```
SELECT 
     `org`.`orgid` AS `orgid`, 
     `org`.`role` AS `role`, 
     `user`.`userid` AS `userid`, 
     `user`.`firstname` AS `firstname` 
FROM 
     `orgTable` AS `org` 
         INNER JOIN `userTable` AS `user` 
         ON `org`.`userid` = `user`.`userid` 
WHERE 
     `org`.`orgid` = '1'
```